# Django REST framework unrecognized

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I already have django rest framework installed in my project, as you see when I run pip freeze: [image]

However, when I try to import any module it does not recognize it, so it is not possible for me to go check the function or class or whatsoever I am importing.

[image]

Who knows what the problem is?

Comment: Did you add `rest_framework` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yes Ene Paul, I did.

Comment: Are you using `venv` ou Docker? And which OS are you using?

Comment: It is IDE related issue. Nothing is wrong with drf. It works fine, never mind.